# How to make a line like this

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I saw this in an app , I was wondering how can I make a similar one .

How can I make it with xml codes instead of 9-patch images ?

[image]

Comment: It could be [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Android XML drawables you can create a uniform fading line i.e. opacity ranges from 0 to 1 and then returns back to 0.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerColor="#ff864316"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

And for using it, you can create a `view` with 1px height.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@drawable/myline"/>
```